# Python3 Sqlite3 - How to Escape executescript Properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a query like this:

```
PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});
UPDATE {0} SET {1} = "{2}" WHERE {1} = "{3}";
```

I use this query to insert & update. But, as you can see, this is a multiline query, so I have to use executescript function, which results that I can't use placeholders like this to avoid injections:

```
PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES (?);
UPDATE {0} SET {1} = "?" WHERE {1} = "?";
```

So, is there a workaround? Do I have to change my approach or escape it without using placeholders? If so, how I can escape it to avoid possible injections? Thanks.

Comment: The more I look at those INSERT and UPDATE queries, the more I get confused. You have INSERT OR IGNORE which implies that the value 2 you're trying to insert is for a unique column 1 and the table might already have a row with that value, but then in the UPDATE you try to set that column 1 to that same value 2 you just tried to insert (In cases where 1's value is currently 3). It would always fail to update because the unique constraint would be violated - either because of the new row you just added, or a pre-existing one...

Comment: @Shawn First one inserts it if there is no duplicate. If there is, does nothing. This is clear for both of us. But, I use the same query for also updating the values. So usage of the latter is to update the query. I use it and it does not fail when ignore happens.

Comment: @Shawn I checked it out with different situations. It works as I expect and doesn't return any errors. Can you explain why you thought it is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting.

```
command = """
PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES (?);
UPDATE {0} SET {1} = {} WHERE {1} = {};
""".format(var1, var2)
```

Comment: As you can see, I already formatted it, just didn't pass it to format function. The real problem isn't formatting it, it is avoiding the SQL Injections. If I just format it, a user might use " in his data, which would give an error and makes SQL Injections possible.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that pragma. It only has meaning when used before any tables are created in a brand new database. [Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding).

Then in your INSERT and UPDATE statements, just use placeholders like normal. (Unfortunately, there's no way to use placeholders to indicate a table or column name, just values, so if those aren't known when you're writing out the query, you have to stick with that string formatting approach for them.)

Comment: I was trying to solve an issue about UTF characters months ago, so it is a cargo cult. Thanks for pointing it out, I will remove it from unnecessary queries.

Still, I have 2 lines. That means I can't use execute without separating the lines.

Comment: @Belial Use two separate prepared statements. (Also you don't want quotes around the placeholder question marks. That makes them not placeholders).

Comment: That means I have to change lots of things. Still, thanks.

Comment: at a quick glance, python3 doesn't appear to have prepared statements, nor support placeholders in a script.